# While using GIMP, how to use the mouse wheel to enlarge and decrease the entire window

Tags: window, gimp

I would like to use the mouse wheel to move enlarge the entire window that I am using in GIMP instead of just zooming in on an area in the window.

How do I accomplish this?

I've looked all through keystroke shortcuts to find an answer and found nothing.

I used to be able to do this all the time in the older version 2.8

Thanks!
Carol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open GIMP, then navigate to *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Input Devices* → *Input Controllers*.
2. From *Active Controllers*, choose *Main Mouse Wheel*.

   [image]
3. Look for *Scroll Up* event, then click *Edit event*; search for *Zoom In*, then click OK.

   [image]
4. Look for *Scroll Down* event

   [image]

   ,then click *Edit event*; search for *Zoom Out*, then click OK.

   [image]
5. Close Main Mouse Wheel; in Preferences window click OK.

Answer (score 1):

Hover the cursor in the window you want to enlarge or decrease, and hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while you scroll the mouse wheel. The whole window gets huge or tiny as you roll the mouse wheel.

Comment: I have tried this in Gimp 2.10.18 and in Gimp 2.10.24 — in single-window- and in separated toolboxes (3-window) modes — and I'm still not sure what you mean. Ctrl+mousescroll zooms _the image_ in and out. But it does not change _the window_ itself. I suspect you might have stumbled upon some accessibility feature that is capable of altering the entire display somehow? (Update: maybe [AEM's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1227088) casts light on this, a change of Gimp configuration may enable this feature?)